# NGINX enable rate limiting only on successful requests

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rate-limiting

Is there are a way to enable rate limiting only for successful requests (i.e. HTTP status code 200)?

For example, in the following snippet from my configuration...

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=test:10m rate=2r/m;

    server {
        location / {
             limit_req zone=test;
             proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
             ...
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

...requests are successfully rate limited (up to two requests per minute).

However, as this is for a contact form which sends me emails, I do not care about rate limiting if `http://localhost:3000/` returns an error as no email will have been sent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Nginx processes HTTP request in 11 phases from reading request to sending reponse: post-read, server-rewrite, find-config, rewrite, post-rewrite, pre-access, access, post-access, try-files, content, log.

`proxy_pass` is in `content phase` while `limit_req` is in `pre-access phase` (refer `ngx_http_limit_req_module.c`), `pre-access phase` handlers is executed before `content phase` handlers, so limit_req handler can not check if the response code is OK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's really helpful! Would it be theoretically possible to write a plugin that did this – it could remove IP addresses from the rate limit zone once it detects a non-OK response code, perhaps right before the log phase?

Comment: I don't know how to write a formal module to make it, but I think it's possible to change source code, refer to [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is not exactly correct. You can actually do (kinda) it.

Note, `try_files` is needed instead of `return`, due to `return`'s short circuiting behavior.

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;

# repeat as needed
error_page <code> = @nein_<code>;
location @nein_<code> {
  internal  ;
  limit_req zone=<zone>;
  try_files /dev/null =<code>;
}
```

Note: this only takes effect AFTER failed auth, so you have to play around with burst limit to delay the next requests. Im not even sure if its possible to secure things this way against brute force attacks.